# Determine Chi Square Group Differences in multiple choice questionnaire

Tags: chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, survey, group-differences

I'm trying to determine if there is a group difference in answering a multiple choice question.

For example, I want to answer the question of, do "Change Instigators" (group A) answer "communication" as a strength more often than the group mean (average of group A, B, and C). You can select up to 2 answers, "communication" being one of 5.

Here's how my data is formulated:

> Q: What's your strength?

```
Strength              Change Instigators     GroupB     GroupC
Communication         300                    100        122
Productivity          200                    212        500
Conflict Resolution   150                    157        130
Vision                216                    256        233
Personnel             350                    300        222
```

What type of analysis do I perform when I'm comparing percentages between groups within a question? Any suggestions for other types of analysis?